# How to get image url using amazon mws report api?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-mws

I am using `GetReport` API of Amazon MWS Actually it's not returning images URL? Is there a way to get image URL?.I am getting all the data which is needed.I am using PHP client library of Amazon MWS.

Answer (score 0):

apparently there is no MWS api to get product images URL, except if you use Amazon Products Advertising API and use ItemLookup using product's ASIN and select fields you want in return. Try this [Products Advertising API ScratchPad](http://associates-amazon.s3.amazonaws.com/scratchpad/index.html)